# How do we get the selected item(s) id from SharePoint Task List Gantt View?

Tags: sharepoint-online, task-list, gantt-view

[image]

As shown in above figure. I have created a list using Task list template and also created a Gantt View of that. I want the selected items ID from that gantt view? How do we get the selected item ID from Gantt View.

Comment: What did you mean get the selected item's id? Here is an article about customizing and navigating the Gantt chart https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-project-tasks-list-view-e6d26b31-c08f-4fcf-b647-1d0f5305bca2#:~:text=The%20Gantt%20chart%2C%20displayed%20on,Gantt%20chart%20using%20the%20ribbon.

Comment: As you see in above screenshot the ID column in the Grid (which is the ID of the tasks) and the item with the ID=1 is selected. Then i want to get that selected task ID value.

Comment: Whether you want to get the GUID of the task list?